# depth of node in a parse tree

Tags: java, netbeans-7, stanford-nlp

I am using stanford-nlp with Java 7 and NetBeans 7.3.1

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    String text = "the dog who bit the man";// Add your text here!
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
    for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
      for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
        String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
        String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
        String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);       
      }
    Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
    System.out.println(tree);
    System.out.println(tree.depth());
```

With this I can get depth of the tree but how can I get the depth of term 'dog' or any other term's depth in this parse tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I came to know that this is a dumb question (very dumb) Sorry :D

Anyway, here's what I learned:

Since the terms/strings of the sentence are represented as leaves in the parse tree, the depth of them will be 0.

So now how to access the term i.e how to iterate the tree to that term/string/leaf ::

```
for (Tree subtree : tree) { 
          if(subtree.label().value().equals("term----xxxx"))
          //You can do your own stuff here 
 }
```